# SQL-Query number of repeat buyers per month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I really need help creating a query where i can show the number of buyers per month categorized by their number of orders.

Below is sample data:

| uid (User ID) | oid (Order ID) | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a1 | 01-01-2020 |
| 1 | a2 | 01-13-2020 |
| 1 | a3 | 02-06-2020 |
| 2 | b1 | 01-17-2020 |
| 3 | c1 | 02-04-2020 |
| 3 | c2 | 03-29-2020 |
| 3 | c3 | 04-08-2020 |
| 3 | c4 | 05-02-2020 |
| 4 | d1 | 03-31-2020 |

Desired output is:

| category | Jan | Feb | March | April | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User with order 1-2 orders | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | ... |
| User with order >2 orders | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | ... |

Basically, orders for each category distributed by month.

Here is my attempt at the script but i cant seem to pivot it into the desired output:

```
WITH 
order_count AS (
SELECT 
   uid, 
   case when count(*)>2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as cnt 
FROM orders group by 1
)

, summary1 AS (
SELECT
    o.uid,o.createdate,oc.cnt
    ,COUNT(o.uid)
FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN order_count oc ON o.uid = oc.uid
GROUP BY 1,2
)

SELECT * FROM summary1
```

Comment: Break your problem into achievable parts. Step 1 is to calculate number of orders per "month" (hint - you need to think about this and consider your very TINY set of sample data) per user. What will happen in 3 weeks when the first order of 2022 is created?

Comment: You need to show us at least some attempt at this problem.

Comment: @Alex hello, i edited it to include script but i cant seem to pivot it.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to extract month from date and use it together with uid to group the records to get the initial count from which category can be calculated. As SMor suggested, it would be advisable to account for year also. This might best be done my including year as an additional column in the result.

Try something like the following. I added a few extra rows of data to actually get a few count(*) > 2 cases and to illustrate multiple years.

```
DECLARE @orders TABLE(uid int, oid VARCHAR(10), [Date] Date)
INSERT @orders
VALUES
    (1, 'a1', '01-01-2020'),
    (1, 'a2', '01-13-2020'),
    (1, 'a3', '02-06-2020'),
    (1, 'a3', '01-01-2021'), -- Added
    (2, 'b1', '01-17-2020'),
    (3, 'c1', '02-04-2020'),
    (3, 'c2', '03-29-2020'),
    (3, 'c3', '04-08-2020'),
    (3, 'c4', '05-02-2020'),
    (4, 'd1', '03-01-2020'),
    (4, 'd2', '04-01-2020'), -- Added
    (4, 'd3', '04-15-2020'), -- Added
    (4, 'd4', '04-30-2020'), -- Added
    (4, 'd5', '05-01-2020'), -- Added
    (4, 'd6', '05-11-2020'), -- Added
    (4, 'd7', '05-21-2020'), -- Added
    (4, 'd8', '05-31-2020'), -- Added
    (5, 'e1', '12-31-2021'), -- Added
    (5, 'e2', '12-31-2021'), -- Added
    (5, 'e3', '12-31-2021')  -- Added

;
WITH order_count AS (
    SELECT o.uid, d.year, d.month, category = CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM @orders o
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT year = YEAR([date]), month = MONTH([date])) d
    GROUP BY o.uid, d.year, d.month
)
SELECT
    category, year,
    Jan=[1], Feb=[2], Mar=[3], Apr=[4], May=[5], Jun=[6],
    Jul=[7], Aug=[8], Sep=[9], Oct=[10], Nov=[11], Dec=[12]
FROM order_count c
PIVOT (
    COUNT(uid)
    FOR month IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
) P
ORDER BY category, year
```

Results:

| category | year | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 2021 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2020 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2021 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |